# convert date time from 12 hour to 24 hour date time without AM/PM in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am just new in R and would like to convert a date time from 12h to 24h but do not have info regarding AM/PM:

```
2018-02-15T12:51:01+00:00
```

Already checked your previous posts related with the same subject but couldn't move forward with any of them

I've started by converting from character to POSIXct

```
data$TimeDate_TimeDate <- as.POSIXct(data$TimeDate_TimeDate, format="%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S+00:00")

data$TimeDate_TimeDate <- format(strptime(data$TimeDate_TimeDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S+00:00"), format="%Y-%m%-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

The result is still with 12h format.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show some more examples of data points?

Comment: Sure!                                                                                                         
2018-02-15T11:54:00+00:00
2018-02-15T11:55:00+00:00
2018-02-15T11:56:00+00:00
2018-02-15T11:57:00+00:00
2018-02-15T11:58:00+00:00
2018-02-15T11:59:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:00:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:01:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:02:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:03:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:04:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:05:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:06:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:07:00+00:00
2018-02-15T12:08:00+00:00

Comment: All these data examples seem to show times around 12 o'clock. Do you get times greater than 12? E.g., 2018-02-15T18:08:00+00:00

Comment: Never, because is in 12h format, but as I do not have any information if it is AM or PM could be both..

Comment: So what should happen to e.g. 11:57 then? Should it be 11:57 or 23:57?

Comment: I need to change from e.g. 2018-02-15T06:00:54+00:00 to 2018-02-15T18:00:54+00:00

Comment: But how do you know it's 6PM and not 6AM? Are you saying you know they're all PM?

Comment: I do not know, but thought it could be any way to find it out

Comment: If these are continuous time series you can tell which one is midnight because the date will change at midnight and not at noon.